# How to convert string to excel named range?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm working on a project where I need to populate some excel named ranges with some data. However I'm receiving the addresses of these named ranges as strings and not `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.NamedRange`. The strings look something like     `Sheet1_A1_D1`. How can I convert these strings to a NamedRange object? are there any predefined methods? Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the strings have a consistent pattern you could split it to an array that holds info needed to locate the needed named range.

Once you get the sheet name and the address cells, you can iterate through the sheets named ranges and compare addresses of each named range with the data you extracted from the string:

```
    private const int SHEET_ARRAY_INDEX = 0;
    private const int RANGE_START_ARRAY_INDEX = 1;
    private const int RANGE_END_ARRAY_INDEX = 2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = "Sheet1_A1_A2";
        string[] rangeInfo = myString.Split('_');

        string sheet = rangeInfo[SHEET_ARRAY_INDEX]; // holds "Sheet1"
        string arrayStart = rangeInfo[RANGE_START_ARRAY_INDEX]; // holds "A1"
        string arrayEnd = rangeInfo[RANGE_END_ARRAY_INDEX]; // holds "A2"
    }
```

For iterating through named ranges please see: https://bishoponvsto.wordpress.com/2009/09/01/reading-named-ranges-in-excel-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

it looks messy and I am betting there is an easier/better way to do this... but this gets it done

```
string sheetRange = "DataSheet1_A1_D1";
string[] splitStringArray = sheetRange.Split('_');
string sheetToGet = splitStringArray[0];
string firstCell = splitStringArray[1];
string lastCell = splitStringArray[2];
// Use the specified sheet
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[sheetToGet];
// Get the full range to work with 
Range currentRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(firstCell + ":" + lastCell, Type.Missing);
// Note here:
// You could use "A","B","C"... etc to specify a column
// However... When the range is returned... The returned range will start on Col "A"
// so the given values wont match anyway...
// However all we need to know though is how many columns are involved

int colCount = currentRange.Columns.Count;
// the variables below are for testing the output
int curRow = 1;
int curCol = 1;

foreach (Range row in currentRange.Rows)
{
  curCol = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
  {
    ((Excel.Range)row.Cells[1, i]).Value2 = "Row: " + curRow + " Column: " + curCol;
    curCol++;
  }
  curRow++;
}
```

Hope This Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can get the range the name refers to like so:

```
range = _excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Names.OfType<Name>().SingleOrDefault(n => n.Visible && n.Name == "rangeName")?.RefersToRange;
```

Another approach is to ask Excel to resolve the address:

```
range = _excelApp.get_Range(address);
```

This would require the address to be specified in one of the following formats:

1. B4
2. Sheet1!B4
3. Sheet1!A1:D1
4. namedRangeName

Option 3 seems to be the way to go since in your case, `Sheet1_A1_D1` doesn't seem to be a named range, it seems like a funky address string. I suggest you replace the first underscore with '!' and the second one with ':' and use the `excelApp.get_range` method.